# Covariance between Linear Combinations of random vectors

Tags: random-variable, covariance

Given a random vector $x\sim N(0, \Sigma)$ of dimension $p$ and matrices $A$ and $B$ (both $m\times p$, what is $Cov(Ax, Bx)$?

It seems to me that the covariance should be $A\Sigma B^T$ but I am second guessing this as the result is not guaranteed to be symmetric positive definite.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Covariance matrices are not symmetric (or even square) in general since the two vectors can be different and have unequal dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
Cov(Ax, Bx) &=  E[(Ax-E(Ax))(Bx-E(Bx))^T]\\
&= E[A(x-E(x))(x-E(x))^TB^T] \\
&=AE[(x-E(x))(x-E(x))^T]B^T \\
&= A\Sigma B^T
\end{align}

While [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is symmetric positive semidefinite, [cross covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance) doesn't have to be.

Note property $4$ at the cross covariance matrix, it is the result of your interest.